# How do I use my intermediate table to show the m2m relationship in my templates?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, many-to-many

I want to be able to see which players are in a team from my team-detail.html file. The team is chosen in my team-list.html.

These are my relevant models:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_column="Player's_Name", blank=True, null=True, max_length=32)
    team = models.CharField(db_column="Player's_Team", blank=True, null=True, max_length=32)
    username = models.CharField(db_column='Username', blank=True, null=True, max_length=32)
    password = models.CharField(db_column='Password', blank=True, null=True, max_length=16)
    email = models.EmailField(db_column='Email', blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(db_column='Bio', blank=True, null=True, max_length=5000)
    # teamid = models.CharField(db_column='TeamID', blank=True, null=True, max_length=8)
    teams = models.ManyToManyField('Team', through='Membership')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('player-detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(db_column='Team_Name', blank=True, null=True, max_length=32)
    playernames = models.TextField(db_column='Players', blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('team-detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class Membership(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('membership-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Here is my team-detail file:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Team Name: {{ team.team_name }}</h1>

  <p><strong>Players:</strong> <a href="{% url 'player-detail' team.membership_set. %}">{{ team.membership_set.all }}</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

I'm not using my own query set, I'm using

```
class TeamDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Team
```

Please let me know if you need any more info.

I am still unable to work this out. Is there an easy one line thing or will I need to edit across multiple files? It's becoming a massive stumbling block and I'd really appreciate any information you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It was way simpler than I imagined.

You simply do

```
{% block content %}
  <h1>Team Name: {{ team.team_name }}</h1>

    <p><strong>Players:</strong></p>
  {% for player in team.membership_set.all %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'player-detail' player.player_id %}">{{ player.player.name }}</a> AKA {{ player.player.account.username }} Joined: {{ player.date_joined }}</li>
  {% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks !! I was searching for days for a solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ManyToMany relationship in Django whitout create the model Team:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

If you need the model Team your code is right, you must see the error in runserver.